# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when uploading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I get this error anytime I try to upload a file in my ASP.NET MVC application. Can anyone help me out. The error thrown is a [System.UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)

> Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IBGTxalert\TxAlert\TxAlert.Web\Files\linqtoexcel.xlsx'
>   is denied.

Comment: (1) Are you correctly mapping to path?    (2) does the user have permissions to that folder ?   (3) have you checked through the details as mentioned in ... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set file access permission to `Network Service` account.

1. In Windows Explorer, locate and select the required folder(ie: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IBGTxalert\TxAlert\TxAlert.Web\Files`).
2. Right-click the folder, and then click Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.
4. On the Security tab, examine the list of users. If the Network
   Service account is not listed, add it.
5. In the Properties dialog box, click the Network Service user name,
   and in the Permissions for NETWORK SERVICE section, select the Read,
   Write, and Modify permissions. Click Apply, and then click OK.

Steps taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx)