# ASP.Net uploading image to wwwroot folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I keep on getting the same error in uploading a image on the published project in IIS: "UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestProj\wwwroot\files\clients\1111_64d96158-2a74-4277-98ed-7b12ba290b2d_CJQYABUT-SAMPLE-ID.jpg' is denied."

I keep on chaging the codes from _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath and ContentRootPath, i tried  using `var uniqueFileName = "wwwroot/files/clients/";`  and still dont work.

Here are some of the codes i tried,

```
string uniqueFileName = null;
                if (client.FirstFile != null)
                {
                    string uploadsFolder ="wwwroot/files/clients/";
                    uniqueFileName = client.Number + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + client.FirstFile.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await client.FirstFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                    client.FilePath = "/files/UploadImages/" + uniqueFileName;
                }
```

```
string uniqueFileName = null;
                if (client.FirstFile != null)
                {
                    string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "files/clients/");
                    uniqueFileName = client.Number + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + client.FirstFile.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await client.FirstFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                    client.FilePath = "/files/UploadImages/" + uniqueFileName;
                }
```

```
string uniqueFileName = null;
                if (client.FirstFile != null)
                {
                    string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot/files/clients/");
                    uniqueFileName = client.Number + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + client.FirstFile.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await client.FirstFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                    client.FilePath = "/files/UploadImages/" + uniqueFileName;
                }
```

I don't know if I'm missing something, please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you granted access permission to Network Service account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221578/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-uploading-a-file

Comment: No, but after seeing this comment I tried following the instruction in the link provided, and unfortunately it has the same result.  I'm kinda new to this and the hard part is I don't have a senior developer to ask assistance.

Comment: Did you added permission in folder afterwards still remain same, Have restarted your IIS app pool? have added permission from IIS folder or C drive? Which user you have added in permission group? These information are crucial.

Comment: I added permission full access of the folder to Admin and my login credentials in the company. I added this Network Service to Read, Write and Modify but still getting the same error. The folder path of the project is located in C drive same to the IIS. I'm confused, when I run my application in Localhost, it works, but in IIS, it doesn't.

Comment: Are there any firewall restrictions? If possible also provide full control to `IIS_IUSRS` and restart your app pool and then try again.

Comment: Sorry late reply, the issues has been solved, by providing full control to IIS_IUSR. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "UnauthorizedAccessException" error message you're seeing is indicating that the user account that the IIS worker process is running under does not have permission to access the specified file path.

There are a few things you can try to resolve this issue:

Make sure that the user account that the IIS worker process is running under (usually "IIS_IUSRS") has read and write access to the folder that you're trying to save the image in.

If you are using a version of IIS less than 8.5, you may need to configure the application pool to run as the "LocalSystem" account, which has the necessary permissions to access the folder.

You can also try to give the permissions for the folder to the "Everyone" group to confirm it's not a permission issue. But keep in mind that giving permissions to the "Everyone" group could be a security risk.

If you're still facing the same issue, you could try checking the file and folder permissions for the folder in Windows.

Another alternative is change the location of the image to be stored, to a folder outside the IIS.

Make sure that after you've made any changes to the file or folder permissions, you restart the IIS worker process for the changes to take effect.